# Is there a word for that sort of sideways chop rappers do when rapping?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not talking about gang signs or whatever, I'm talking about the hand emotes while rapping.

The gestures that tell you someone's rapping instead of singing even in a still picture.

I assume it sort of comes from old school DJ's on a turntable, but I don't know if anyone ever named it.

Comment: Holding your hand, palm down, and moving from side to side, is a very common way of gesturing "no", "no way", "shut up and do what I say", etc. A similar gesture is shown [here](https://www.scienceofpeople.com/hand-gestures/) identified as "you listen to me". Is that the gesture you want? It would help to have a photo or video; it should be within most people's capabilities to video themselves.

Comment: 1) Not to my knowledge, but I'll be interested to learn if there is. 2) Part of the issue is that not every microcomponent of a culture is named. Especially physical postures and gestures that are *not* charged with specific meaning themselves, but simply contextual. Is there a name for classical pianists' tendency to lean their head back with their eyes closed? No, but they sure do it...

Comment: @AndyBonner - That’s called “emoting”.